# javascript: explanation needed for this piece of code

Tags: javascript, class, methods, this, self

Who can explain me this code (alert `"Hi! My name is Mark"` appears):

```
function Person(name) {
    var self = this;
    this.name = name;

    function person(){
        alert("Hi! My name is "+self.name);
    }
    return {person:person};
}

new Person("Mark").person();
```

and why I don't see alert if `return {person:person};` is removed? What `person:person` is here?

Also, why `this.name` (not self.name) is undefined in `function person(){}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you should not return {person:person}, but you should not specify a return or "return this;".

new Person("Mark") will create an instance of Person, but the function Person returns the {person:person}. Inside {person:person} the right one(value) is the method.
var x = new Person("Mark") will return {person: function person(){alert("Hi...")}.
x.person() will show the alert.

Answer (score 1):

This code is very tricky:

```
function Person(name) { 
    //'P' makes us think about this function as a constructor
    var self = this; 
    // Closure, when the person function is executed
    //"this" is not a Person, is another object, but "self" will be accesible
    // by the function person

    this.name = name;

    // this is an internal function, it does not exist out of Person
    function person(){ 
        alert("Hi! My name is "+self.name);
    }
    return {person:person}; 
    //This should not be here if the Person function were a proper constructor,
    //it returns an object which only attribute is the function person
}

new Person("Mark").person(); 
// as Person returns an object (not a Person object) with the person attribute,
// you can call that attribute
```

The equivalent but clearer code to this one is:

```
var p={
      person: function () {
          var self={name: "Mark"};
          (function(){ 
              alert("Hi! My name is "+ self.name);
           })();
        }
      };
p.person();
```

Comment: Sorry, you code is not an equivalent as it doesn't display the alert with name, the name is undefined.  You code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/3sC7z/  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Niels' answer is correct, and to answer the rest of your question, this.name doesn't work inside the child function because name belongs to the parent function so you have to declare an instance of that parent scope (in your case self) to be able to access the properties of the parent.